# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, dict found

Tags: python, matplotlib

Anyone know how to solve this error?

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, dict found
```

Can you help me??

Comment: Care to share the piece of code that produces this error?

Comment: Seriously man, no code? How can you possibly expect any help?

Comment: Can you please describe a bit more your problem, for instance by adding your code ?

Comment: http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/20722667.jpg

Comment: I can load the initial screen of the project, but when you click
"generate graph" it does not display the graph and if I click with right click and view image ... shows this error. In this case the matplotlib is installed.

See my code: http://dpaste.com/750754/

Comment: @David: that should be in the body of your question. Then too, put the traceback. And try to trim down the code to produce a minimal example with the failure.

Comment: Any insight on ur part for this code?

Comment: An example of the code would be great to help us help you =)

Answer (score 4):

You are giving dictionary where a string or buffer was expected.

You should check your code or debug around the line you get the Exception, check if all the functions that expect a string aren't getting a dictionary instead.

You probably forgot to index a dictionary.

Comment: See the Traceback: http://dpaste.com/750773/ 
I'm not able to solve this. Can anyone help me??

Comment: If you see the traceback your call to `canvas.print_pdf` is the part of [your code](http://dpaste.com/750754/) generating the error, like i said before, you are passing a dict instead of a string somewhere, so probably `response` is expected to be a string and it is defined as a dict. I really have no experience with matplot, i can't help you further, you'll have to research yourself a bit

Comment: Ah ha, that's it -- running matplotlib.get_configdir() gave me the location C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\.matplotlib (WinXP), and removing the fontList.cache file solved the problem. 

tHANKS

Comment: Next time, take your time when creating the question, give more information, show the problematic portion of code, post the whole error message and traceback, tell us what have you tried and you'll have a better response from StackOverflow users.

Answer (score 1):

This error is quite general as others have pointed out. However, it seems that in this context it is caused by a problem in matplotlibs font manager. I ran into a similar problem when trying to use Latex with matplotlib, and was able to fix it by deleting fontList.cache from the matplotlib.get_configdir() directory as David suggested.